# Error generating Service Fabric deployment packages

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I have created a Service Fabric (SF) project with more than 1 services. Locally the solution compiles fine and the SF deployment packages are generated when I right-click the `.sfproj` and select the option Package.

On Visual Studio Team Services I am able to compile the solution but there is an error when I try to generate the SF deployment packages, my task is configured as follows:

[image: VSTS task - generate packages]

The first time I tried to run the build it failed:

> ServiceFabricDemo1\ServiceFabricDemo1\ServiceFabricDemo1\ServiceFabricDemo1.sfproj
>   (3, 3) The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Service Fabric
>   Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationProject.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I copied the `Service Fabric Tools` folder to the team project folder and edited the `.sfproj` file to point to this folder and committed the changes, but the build is still failing in the generation of the SF deployment packages task, this time with the following error message:

> ServiceFabricDemo1\ServiceFabricDemo1\Stateless1\Stateless1.csproj (0,
>   0) The target "_UpdateServiceFabricApplicationManifest" does not exist
>   in the project.

What can I do to fix this problem? I was wondering if there is any nuget package containing all files needed (`*.targets`, etc) to generate the packages or a way to install the tools in VSTS?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. You'll have to use a custom build server with the Service Fabric SDK installed.

Have a look at the "Set up your build machine" section [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration/).

Comment: There must be a workaround such as copying some folders/files from the MSBuild folder and then changing the references/imports on the project file.

Answer (score 0):

Hosted build agent does not have Service Fabric SDK installed, you need to [deploy your own build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/windows) and install the SDK on it as charisk mentioned. You can also submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) for this.